# How does a magnetic field escape a black hole?

Tags: magnetic-fields

In [this article](https://eventhorizontelescope.org/blog/astronomers-image-magnetic-fields-edge-m87s-black-hole) it shows the first photographs and describes the magnetic field surrounding a black hole. How can what is inside the black hole influence what is outside?  Would this imply that information from inside the black hole is getting out (i.e. if I tossed a magnet in, would it change the magnetic field)? Would this imply that the magnetic field is moving faster than c in order to escape the black hole? What is the mechanism by which a black hole (or a bar magnet for that matter) generates the surrounding field that seems impervious to the rules of relativity?

Answer (score 2):

I just watched [this video](https://eventhorizontelescope.org/blog/astronomers-image-magnetic-fields-edge-m87s-black-hole) and it answered my question at the 10 minute mark.  Nothing, including the magnetic field, can escape the black hole.  The magnetic field is pulled in towards the black hole along with any material.  The black hole itself does not have a magnetic field in the way that a planet has a magnetic field.